# 19" PSD printed as 19'...Where did I go wrong?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production

I'm in the early stages of designing a silk screen for a product panel.

I threw together a mockup in Photoshop so I could tape it on top of a current plate panel and present it to the decision makers (they're very much "print people").

Brought my PNG into Staples to get it printed. I told them that the print size was 19" x 3.5". They asked if that was the size of the document, I told them it should already be at that size.

When I went to pick it up, it was 19 feet instead of 19 inches wide.

### Questions

1. Did I do something wrong here? *(Other than having Staples print my work)*
2. Do inches in Photoshop translate to feet in print?
3. How can I improve my workflow to prevent this issue in the future?

**PSD information**

- Image size = 19" x 3.5"
- PPI = 400

[image: photoshop image size info]

**PNG information**

- Image size = 7600px x 1400px (same as PSD)

[image: PNG image size info]

**The image in question**

[image: the silk screen design]

Comment: Did you or the ordering person write the word "inches" or use tick marks? Most likely, the operator does not recognize, or was confused by, the tick marks. PNG files do have a field for DPI/PPI, but it is a derived number and just a stored flag, not data like the pixel info. The operator can specify any size and the *effective PPI* is simply recalculated.

Comment: @Yorik in the typed specifications to the printer (Staples in this case), I specified size like this... 19 x 3.5" (inches).

Comment: Just had to send this https://vimeo.com/94459739 haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand how you rely on " or '. Simply use the word "inches".

It has nothing to do with your document, but a human error*. An operator can simply assign any unit when printing. Meters, feet, inches, centimeters...

(I am not sure who's human error was this. Provider or yours. Probably both. Take a look at your order and see what dimension and price are stipulated.)

Comment: I actually specified inches to them in 3 ways. Tick marks, the written word "inches", and (because I went in person) the spoken word "inches".  I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something really weird with my document sizes since I did tell them to print it "at the file's size". Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Oh. Ok. Then it is a specific error from the provider.